# detect whether .m file is matlab or mathematica

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, file-type

I have been editing Matlab script in Vim for some time now. Recently I started taking an interest in moving my Mathematica work to plain text files so they can be managed using git and edited using Vim. Unfortunately Mathematica also uses the `.m` extension for its package files and is therefore not easily distinguished from Matlab scripts. Since I would like my editor to do the work for me I was wondering if anyone has come up with an idea for identifying both based on the contents of the file. I would be fine with something that works in most cases, but am reluctant to use a solution that requires alterations in the scripts such as adding a comment.

Comment: Recent versions of mathematica now take .wl  extension same as .m

Answer (score 1):

A ".mat" or ".m" file created with MATLAB's save() function will always start with the plain text identifier "MATLAB". So, using MATLAB syntax, you might do this:

```
% Set up a workspace variable and save to file
tmp = 1:10;
save('test.m');

% Open the file, read the first line and close again
fid=fopen('test.m');
firstline=fgetl(fid);
fclose(fid);

% Branch depending on file format
if ((numel(firstline) >= 6) && strcmp(firstline(1:6), 'MATLAB'))
    disp('This may well be a MATLAB file.');
else
    disp('This is probably not a MATLAB file.');
end
```

Comment: My custom files do not start with the comment, so that would be an issue. I will probably stick to the suggestion of @agentp as that nicely separates between the two filetypes and I'm not getting much code from others.